# Send email to specific users when Webform submitted

Tags: 7, rules, webforms

How can I send emails to specific user roles when a specific Webform is submitted?

For example if a Webform named test is submitted then we have to send email to all users having the role say 'editor'.

Comment: Is this a custom form using the form API, or a form like eg. node edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done by combining [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [Webform Rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules) Modules

In Rules Module You could use the following Settings:

**Events:** `After a webform has been submitted`

**Conditions:** `User has role(s)` and `Webform has name` (to apply for particular webform)

**Actions:** `Send HTML e-mail`

Comment: Can we set the Rule for a particular webform or it is generalize for all web form.

Comment: Yes its possible have to add another condition: "Webform has name"

Comment: After select Events: After a webform has been submitted condition: "Webform has name" is not show. Iam using Drupal 6.

Comment: Not in "events" section you should check it in "conditions"

Comment: its also possible to send emails to all users of sites.